# Pipe two commands in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, asynchronous, pipe

I need to transform a CLI into a "spawn" syntax in nodejs, and I got into a little mess, couldn't figure out from the docs what to do with it.

the syntax is something like this:

```
 somecommand -a op1 -b op2 | othercommand -c op1 -d op2
```

The "othercommand" should get "live" output from "somecommand". and I want to monitor "othercommand"'s output.

Thanks, Tal.

Comment: Maybe gulp with the gulp-run package can solve it: https://github.com/cbarrick/gulp-run

Answer (score 2):

In your somecommand.js, write your output to process.stdout, in othercommand.js, pipe process.stdin to a stream such as though, doing your work with the stream, then pipe the stream to process.stdout

Comment: I don't deal with javascript, i deal with BASH commands. kinda like ps aux | grep 'something'